# Can we use WC_Products_Query to get products that matches a desired product name?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a requirement such that:

1. User searches for a product
2. Any product name that has a match for at least one word of the search string must be returned
3. It must be in the descending order, with the top result having the most number of matching words
4. The short or long description of the product is not required to be checked for keywords

> Possible solutions using `[do_shortcode]` generates unwanted HTML, it is undesired.

```
$products = wc_get_products(array(
  'category'                              => array($brand_slug),
  'status'                                => 'publish',
  'limit'                                 => 20,
  'orderby'                               => 'date',
  'order'                                 => 'DESC',
  'return'                                => 'objects'
  'query'                                 => array(
    'title'                               => $title // Something like this
  )
));
```

Expected output for search query `samsung galaxy mobile`:

> samsung galaxy s10+
>
> samsung qled tv
>
> galaxy chocolate
>
> microsoft surface mobile pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your query with follows -

```
$products = wc_get_products(array(
  'category'                              => array($brand_slug),
  'status'                                => 'publish',
  'limit'                                 => 20,
  'orderby'                               => 'date',
  'order'                                 => 'DESC',
  'return'                                => 'objects'
  's'                                     => $title, // Something like this
));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. Alas, it did not work. [Source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.3.5/includes/class-wc-product-query.php)

Comment: I changed my method to do it this way.